# Generate JavaScript Intellisense Documentation Comments with CoffeScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, coffeescript, xml-comments

I am working with CoffeeScript and I want to supply Visual Studio 2010 JavaScript Intellisense hints as for example Jquery does.
The comments have to be in the format

```
///<summary>Description of the Function</summary>
```

The only way I can see to generate comments is with ###, but then the comment is styled

```
/* 
   <summary>Description of the Function</summary> 
*/
```

And this doesn't work in Studio. Is there way to do it with CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CoffeeScript feature of [embedding javascript](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded), using backticks:

```
`///<summary>Description of the Function</summary>`
```

Comment: *Zing!* Sorry, I don't think I can help you with that. Might be an idea to skip CoffeeLint and run JSLint on the generated javascript instead?